# Select first form element of page, html

Tags: html, authentication

Our login page of our store when loading selects the first form element of "account aanmaken", but we want it to select the first element of "Inloggen" called "Email". How can we do this?

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsLAI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [autofocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus) attribute on your `<input>` element to choose where the focus should go when the page is loaded.

Example:

```html
<input type="email" name="email" autofocus>
```